# RegEx needed to help rename some files

Tags: regex

```
[2.01] The Dundies.avi
[10.16] Valentine's Day.avi
```

I need to rename them to

```
S01E01 - The Dundies.avi
S10E16 -  Valentine's Day.avi
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't it be `S02E01`?  What language/library?

Comment: The only tricky thing is adding the leading zero to the first number. But it should be pretty straightforward in any langage that allows calculating the result instead of using a literal replacement, e.g. PHP `preg_replace_callback()` or Perl with `s/regexp/replacement/e`.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want a combination of regex and code:

To find the numbers:

[(\d+).(\d+)]

For padding 1 --> 01, not sure how easily that can be done in a regex. (why I'm saying you might need code in combination with a regex.